# How to loop over an object array to solve simple sums

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

My object array looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "0",
    "title": "Exercise",
    "main_object": {
      "title": "Exercise",
      "number1": {
        "1": "10",
        "2": "10",
        "3": "5",
        "4": "20",
      },
      "sumtype": {
        "1": "+",
        "2": "-",
        "3": "x",
        "4": ":",
      },
      "number2": {
        "1": "10",
        "2": "5",
        "3": "2",
        "4": "2",
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Now how would I use this to create an array in javascript (and jquery if it has an easier way of doing this) that has the answers to these simple sums. So the first string in the array would be 10 + 10 which would give 20. The second string should be 10 - 5 giving 5.

I use $.getJSON to retrieve my JSON and I tried a simple for loop like this:

```
var sumanswers = [];
var keyamount = Object.keys(exerSumType);
var keylength = keyamount.length;
for (i = 0; i < keylength; i++) {
    sumanswers[i] = exerNumber1[i] + exerSumType[i] + exerNumber2[i];
}
```

This just gives me the sum as a string (e.g. "10+10") while I want "20". Other then that for some reason this doesn't give me all the sums, it gives me this when I console.log(sumanswers):

```
0: NaN
1: "10+10"
2: "10-5"
3: "5x2"
```

So I'm missing my last sum and getting NaN as a first sum for some reason.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
var exercises = [{
  "id": "0",
  "title": "Exercise",
  "main_object": {
    "title": "Exercise",
    "number1": {
      "1": "10",
      "2": "10",
      "3": "5",
      "4": "20",
    },
    "sumtype": {
      "1": "+",
      "2": "-",
      "3": "x",
      "4": ":",
    },
    "number2": {
      "1": "10",
      "2": "5",
      "3": "2",
      "4": "2",
    }
  }
}]

var sumanswers = [];
var keyamount = Object.keys(exerSumType);
var keylength = keyamount.length;
for (i = 0; i < keylength; i++) {
  sumanswers[i] = exerNumber1[i] + exerSumType[i] + exerNumber2[i];
  console.log(sumanswers[i] , exerNumber1[i] , exerSumType[i] , exerNumber2[i])
}
```

Comment: why do you have an array of a single object? do you could have more? where should the result go to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an array for enumerable data. Arrays are zero based, so the index starts from zero.

For calculating some value with a given operand, you could take an object with all operands as keys.

```js
var data = [{ id: "0", title: "Exercise", main_object: { title: "Exercise", number1: { "1": "10", "2": "10", "3": "5", "4": "20" }, sumtype: { "1": "+", "2": "-", "3": "x", "4": ":" }, number2: { "1": "10", "2": "5", "3": "2", "4": "2" } } }],
    op = {
        '+': (a, b) => +a + +b,
        '-': (a, b) => a - b,
        'x': (a, b) => a * b,
        ':': (a, b) => a / b
    };

data.forEach(({ main_object }) => {
    main_object.answers = {};
    var { answers, number1, number2, sumtype } = main_object;
    Object
        .keys(main_object.number1)
        .forEach(k => answers[k] = op[sumtype[k]](number1[k], number2[k]))
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: why using the `+` only for the first function works `+a + +b` without needing to add it for he others ( `a - b` .. )

Comment: because the operands works only for numbers and string are converted to numbers. for strings, addition works as well, but yields not the wanted numerical result.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much! Only change I made is I made the answers into its own array (sumanswers instead of main_object.answers) because it doesn't need to go back to json later but that was simple enough to do on my own. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working snippet suing **ES6**; `Object.keys`, `Array.reduce`, `Spread operator`, `Dynamic key name`.

```js
const obj = {
  number1: {
    1: '10',
    2: '10',
    3: '5',
    4: '20',
  },
  sumtype: {
    1: '+',
    2: '-',
    3: 'x',
    4: ':',
  },
  number2: {
    1: '10',
    2: '5',
    3: '2',
    4: '2',
  },
};

function makeOp(n1, op, n2) {
  return ({
    '+': () => n1 + n2,
    '-': () => n1 - n2,
    'x': () => n1 * n2,
    ':': () => n1 / n2,
  }[op])();
}

const res = Object.keys(obj.number1).reduce((tmp, x) => ({
  ...tmp,

  [x]: makeOp(Number(obj.number1[x]), obj.sumtype[x], Number(obj.number2[x])),
}), {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var test = [
          {
            "id": "0",
            "title": "Exercise",
            "main_object": {
              "title": "Exercise",
              "number1": {
                "1": "10",
                "2": "10",
                "3": "5",
                "4": "20",
              },
              "sumtype": {
                "1": "+",
                "2": "-",
                "3": "x",
                "4": ":",
              },
              "number2": {
                "1": "10",
                "2": "5",
                "3": "2",
                "4": "2",
              }
            }
          }
        ]



        var test = [
          {
            "id": "0",
            "title": "Exercise",
            "main_object": {
              "title": "Exercise",
              "number1": {
                "1": "10",
                "2": "10",
                "3": "5",
                "4": "20",
              },
              "sumtype": {
                "1": "+",
                "2": "-",
                "3": "x",
                "4": ":",
              },
              "number2": {
                "1": "10",
                "2": "5",
                "3": "2",
                "4": "2",
              }
            }
          }
        ]

        test.forEach(ele=> {
        for (let index in ele.main_object.number1){

            var text = ele.main_object;
             var num1  = text.number1[index];
             var op = text.sumtype[index];
             op = op === 'x' ? "*" : op
            op = op === ':' ? "/" : op
             var num2 = text.number2[index];
              console.log(num1 + text.sumtype[index] + num2 +'=' + eval(num1 + op + num2))

        }

        })
```

Answer (score -1):

### `Eval` for the win!

Use `eval(string)` to execute the string as if it were plain old JavaScript

```
sumanswers.map(sumanswer => eval(sumanswer))
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: To the downvoter(s) - it is actually a pretty good example of eval is not evil here.

Comment: However `:` and `x` are not valid operators

Comment: Well, I have no clue what operation `':'` is and you can replace the `'x'` with `'*'`

Comment: It do not fully answer. What about the `NaN` problem?

Comment: The `NaN` error is an off-by-one error. Your loop starts at `0`, but your math objects start with `"1"`

Comment: The `:` is the 4th operator. i.e.   /

Comment: But what is it supposed to do